# Codeigniter 404 issue on every URL other than index

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have got a client who has website in CI .

When i downloaded the website and try to host it . The index page is loading but other than all other links are giving `404 ERROR`

the route looks like this

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');



$route['default_controller'] = "chipili";
$route['404_override'] = '';


$route['how-it-works']      = "chipili/Commentcamarche/";
```

The chipili Controller is like this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Chipili extends CI_Controller {

    protected $data = array();

    function __construct ()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['title'] = 'domain : un spectacle à la maison';
        $this->data['meta_title'] = 'domain : un spectacle à la maison';
        $this->data['meta_desc'] = 'domain : un spectacle à la maison';

        //$this->data['lang'] = 'fr';
        $this->data['content']  = 'index/index';

        //$this->redirectCountry();

    }

    public function redirectCountry() {
        include(APPPATH.'libraries/geoplugin.php');
        $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
        $geoplugin->locate();
        $country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;

        if($country_code == 'FR'){
                if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != 'www.domain.com'){
                    header('Location: http://www.domain.com');
                }
        }
        elseif ($country_code == 'AE'){
            if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != 'ae.domain.com'){
                    header('Location: http://ae.domain.com');
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * 
     */

    public function set_language () {       
        switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']){
            case 'www.domain.com':
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'fr');
                break;
            case 'en.domain.com';
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'en');
                break;
            case 'ae.domain.com';
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'ae');
                break;
            default:
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'fr');
                break;  
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {


        $this->set_language();
        $this->lang->load('index', $this->session->userdata('lang'));

        $this->data['title'] = $this->lang->line('title');
        $this->data['meta_title'] = $this->lang->line('meta_title');
        $this->data['meta_desc'] = $this->lang->line('meta_desc');
        $this->data['content']  = 'index/index';

        $this->load->vars($this->data);
        $this->load->view('template');
    }
 /**
 * Page Comment ca marche
 * url : concert-et-spectacle-a-domicile
 * 
 */

public function Commentcamarche () {
    $this->data['title'] = "How it work";
    $this->data['meta_title'] = "How it work";
    $this->data['meta_desc'] = "How it work";

    $this->data['content']  = 'chipili/commentcamarche';

    $this->load->vars($this->data);
    $this->load->view('template');
}

}
```

**.htaccess**

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .html

Options +FollowSymlinks

ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 months"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|css|js|robots\.txt|citelis|cgi-bin|medias|uploads|favicon\.ico|sitemap\.xml)  

Options +FollowSymlinks
php_flag display_errors on
```

I am a Laravel Dev from my experience i feel it might be permission issue with the folder .

Would be glad if some one could help

Comment: check first whether your URL is working with `index.php` before controller name like `demo.com/index.php/how-it-works`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam which page I'll be adding this ? ,Sorry I am really new to CI

Comment: show your URL you tried and which giving you 404 error

Comment: @RejoanulAlam so this works `http://domain.dev.com` but this do not work `http://domain.dev.com/what-is-chipili` , DO I need to make any changes in the .htacess file as well , SInce the website was on live server now I have installed on my local

Comment: Now check whether it is work `http://domain.dev.com/index.php/what-is-chipili` if works then htaccess issue

Comment: @RejoanulAlam yes it works

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this your htaccess issue. Make your `.htaccess` file in root directory as following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Before that make sure you have set `index_page` as blank in `config.php`

so it should be

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and now both URL will work `http://domain.dev.com/index.php/what-is-chipili` and `http://domain.dev.com/what-is-chipili`

Comment: I checked both and added the code that you gave in .htaccess of the root directory but its still not working I restarted my Apache service also

Comment: Now test by changing `$config['uri_protocol']` (in config.php) as `QUERY_STRING` if still not worked then test `REQUEST_URI` and if experience again same issue then `PATH_INFO`

Comment: so I should change the value of that config to `QUERY_STRING` right ?

Comment: yes try another TWO available option there i.e `REQUEST_URI` or `PATH_INFO`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125665/discussion-between-vikram-and-rejoanul-alam).